# Echosign API emails

Tags: echosign

I can't find the answer anywhere. I have a system that is looking to integrate with the EchoSign API. Its a portal system that will allow the users to upload a document and send it out for approval (to potentially several people). Currently the document will be sent using the standard echoSign email which directs the users to the echosign site.

What I want to be able to do is drive the user to the portal page by sending a document ready for signing email which directs them to the portal (preferably straight to the doc for signing). Where they would login and we would authenticate them and then show them the document ready for signing.

Is the above possible or will the user always be directed to the EchoSign page for signing documents?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: I don't know echosign but I didn't understand what you were trying to do. You might try to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this workflow by using EchoSign Widgets which are embeddable signable agreements

Visit http://www.formerator.com/ for a sample widget

You can create widgets through API by using the end-points on widget resources

https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/widgets/